# Did more than 2,000 television sets a year explode in Moscow alone, causing injuries and fires?

Tags: soviet-union

Paul Milgrom and John Roberts ([1992](https://books.google.com/books?id=3xK7AAAAIAAJ&q=%22The+goods+that+were+available+were+relatively+expensive%22)) state without providing any sources:

> The goods that were available were relatively expensive, shoddy, and often unsafe. For example, more than 2,000 television sets a year exploded in Moscow alone, causing injuries and fires.

Comment: https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1987-02-01-me-580-story.html In Poland (where Rubins were only "non-capitalists" color tv-sets) we joked that USSR could win the Afghan war by saving on explosives and just sending them Rubins.